# Exigir preechimento de input text com jQuery validator

Tags: jquery, formulário, jquery-validate

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro, e tenho três campos para inserir valores.

Quero fazer com que seja obrigatório preencher pelo menos um dos três input text.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso com jQuery Validator?

```html
<input type="text" name="produto_preco_p" id="produto_preco_p" class="form-control" value="<?= $produto_preco_p; ?>" placeholder="Preço tamanho P">

<input type="text" name="produto_preco_m" id="produto_preco_m" class="form-control" value="<?= $produto_preco_m; ?>" placeholder="Preço tamanho M">

<input type="text" name="produto_preco_g" id="produto_preco_g" class="form-control" value="<?= $produto_preco_g; ?>" placeholder="Preço tamanho G">
```

Comment: Por que você não utiliza um radio  para o usuário escolher qual o tamanho e deixa apenas um input text para pegar o valor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que seja obrigatório pelo menos um dos três, sugiro criar uma regra que receba como parâmetro um seletor (uma class por exemplo) comum entre os outros campos para validação, após isso você pode varrer e verificar se algum dos campos possuem valor.

Html:

```
<input type='text' class="toValidate" requiredBased=".toValidate" />
<input type='text' class="toValidate" requiredBased=".toValidate" />
<input type='text' class="toValidate" requiredBased=".toValidate" />
```

JavaScript:

```
//Crio a regra
$.validator.addMethod("requiredBased", function(value, element, param) {
  //passo pelo seletor verificando se todos tem val()
  return (($(param).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).length > 0) ? true : false);
}, "");
```

Segue [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/5RrGa/1593/).

Comment: Perfeito, Brunno! Era isso mesmo. Ia perguntar como faço para colocar mensagem de erro na validação, mas vi que é só inserir o texto entre as aspas no final. Obrigado pela diga!

Answer (score 1):

O mais "fácil" seria usar o *required* do HTML5, mas ele vai tornar obrigatório todos os campos.

```
<input type="text" name="produto_preco_p" id="produto_preco_p" class="form-control" value="<?= $produto_preco_p; ?>" placeholder="Preço tamanho P" required>
```

Se tua aplicação permite, obriga o preenchimento de todos os campos e trata depois no momento da inserção. (Por exemplo: Não tem preço do tamanho G, orienta o usuário a por 0 no campo e depois veja o que vai fazer, se insere o 0 no banco ou transforma em null).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Diego!